# PHP - Loops and multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have been reading through a lot of other posts here, but does really solve my problem. I am accessing data from a MySQL DB: image IDs and image names. I can easily get the information with:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo $row['name'];

}
```

I am fetching an image name here which I need to write a loop to insert the images in another array like this:

```
$newItem = array(

//stuff like name, id, tax id etc.
//...
//,

'images' => array(
    array(
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg',
        'description' => 'My image',

         ),

    array(
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/images/image2.jpg',
        'description' => 'My Image 2',
         ),

//maybe more images here ...

    ),
```

My first attempt to solve this was to put the fetched data into a variable:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // DB access - > $row['name']

    $images .=
    array(
        'link'        => $imguri.$row['name'], //$imguri is the server link
        'description' => 'My image', //not important


         ).','; //with or without comma -> no success
    }
```

and then insert the variable:

```
'images' => array($images),
```

But that does not work. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$newItem = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    $newItem['images'][] = array(
        'link'        => $imguri.$row['name'],
        'description' => 'My image'
    );
}

var_dump($newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing strings and arrays. Simply create an empty array, and add elements to it in the loop:

```
$images = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

    $images[] =
    array(
        'link'        => $imguri.$row['name'], //$imguri is the server link
        'description' => 'My image', //not important    
         );
}

//
'images' => $images;
```

Comment: @Shockproof please elaborate on 'doesnt work' - perhaps update your question with your current, not working code, and include the error messages you are getting

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough: when I "print_r" oder "var_dump" the arrays, they are always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use php array_push() method in your while loop.
$images['images']=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $image=
    array(
        'link'        => $imguri.$row['name'], 
        'description' => 'My image', 
         );
array_push($images['images'],$image);
}

Comment: var_dump shows me: array(1) { ["images"]=> array(0) { } } -- So unfortuantely it does not work

Comment: you mean var_dump($images['images']);?

Comment: yes. please check if your query returning any output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the DB query and now it works for me.